# JS errors on SE business site

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, stackoverflow-business

Going to [stackoverflow business page](http://business.stackoverflow.com/) I see the following javascript errors in the console:

> oct.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>
> B2B-SO-Global.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tested in Chrome incognito mode, so no cookies are involved. This seems to be on every page.

Another error at `/advertise` shows the missing image link:

> http://business.stackoverflow.com/content/img/sales/map.svg 404 (Not Found) from jquery.min.js

Comment: Fixed the TypeError, have to look into the missing image and oct.js (looks like Twitter tracking code). This is on our radar.

Comment: Btw. `© 2015` is [here](http://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise).

Comment: @kenorb maybe it's by design, i.e. no development was done on the page since 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved a while back, but we neglected to update this post.  Marking as completed now.  Thanks for reporting it initially.